# navigationBar is out of synch with application UI after rotation with MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen video

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, mpmovieplayercontroller, master-detail

This is a master-detail app and this bug only occurs when rotating iPhone while video is playing in fullscreen mode.

Once video closes the navigationBar is positioned higher than normal and is slightly hidden under iPhone status bar.

How can I programmatically set the navigation bar?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352045/extremely-weird-behavior-of-navigationbar-and-mpmovieplayercontroller-bug-in-io/8372481#8372481