# Extremely weird behavior of navigationBar and MPMoviePlayerController. Bug in iOS or my error?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a `MPMoviePlayerController` object that plays a video fullscreen in either portrait or landscape.  If I rotate orientation while the video is playing and do the rotation within a few seconds after the video starts playing and the video status bar is visible, when the video ends my navigation bar is perfect.  But if I wait until the video status bar disappears a few seconds into the video playing and then rotate orientation, when the video ends my `navigationBar` is partially hidden behind the status bar, like pushed up.

Have you ever seen something like this?

I am able to recreate this bug easily. I created a new Single View App and simply added a button and a navigation bar.  If I rotate orientation while video is playing, tap to enable fullscreen and the video status bar is still visible, when the video finishes, all is good.  But, if I wait to rotate after the video status bar disappears, when I rotate and the video finishes, the navigationBar is under the status bar.  See image:

[iPhone Image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/56199731@N06/6448003523/in/photostream)

Here is the simple code I am using:

```
- (void) playMovie {
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"movie" ofType: @"mov"]];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
                                         selector: @selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object: moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

[self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen: YES animated: YES];

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification *) notification
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self 
                                                name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                              object: player];

if ([player respondsToSelector: @selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
{
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Here is where I am currently at with the suggestions given below.  I must have something wrong because unfortunately I still have the same problem.

Here is the method `onPlayerWillExitFullScreen`

```
UIView *view = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.subviews lastObject];    
if (view) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window addSubview:view]; 
}

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self 
                                                name: MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
                                              object: player];
```

and here is my current `playMovie` method:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"movie" ofType: @"mov"]];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
                                         selector: @selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object: moviePlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver: self
                                        selector: @selector(onPlayerWillExitFullScreen:) 
                                            name: MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
                                          object: self.moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

[self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen: YES animated: YES];
```

Comment: You may want to include a screenshot or two.

Comment: Your link to screenshot is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I found this freaking same bug all over my app first in a UIWebView then in a MPMoviePlayerController, I solved this placing this code in my view controller.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Tricky bugs, tricky fixes.

Comment: Finally!! Thank you so much.  I had to play with a bit but got it to work.  I placed the code inside of my -(void) movieFinished: (NSNotification *) aNotification

Answer (score 5):

If you listen for the MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification notification, you can force your main views to redraw properly as follows. The 'window' referenced is your application's main UIWindow object.

When MPMoviePlayerController switched to fullscreen, it actually creates a separate UIWindow instance to present the video. By catching the notification as it transitions back, this code will ensure the views you're switching back to correctly realign.

Admittedly, this is not an elegant solution, but it does work every time.

```
UIView *view = [window.subviews lastObject];
if (view) {
     [view removeFromSuperview];
     [window addSubview:view];
}
```

To listen for this notification, you'll need to do something like this, where self.playerController is your MPMoviePlayerController object.

Remember to stop listening for this notification once you release the player though!

```
    // Determine the default notification centre
    NSNotificationCenter *centre = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    // Listen for interesting movie player notifications
    [centre addObserver: self
               selector: @selector(onPlayerWillExitFullScreen:) 
                   name: MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
                 object: self.playerController];
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I am new to programming so I am not super sure how to implement that notification but I am going to give it a shot.  I am super relieved to know there is a solution.

Comment: Updated my answer to include this for you.

Comment: I am confused as to the UIWindow object.  Take my simple test application, all I have is a Single View App with only a button and a navigationBar.  I tried to sub "window" with "self.view" but must not be correct.

Comment: In your application delegate you'll have a reference to a UIWindow object - this is the one you want.

Comment: Thanks for your tremendous patience!  In my app delegate file it refers to the UIWindow *window which is synthesized as window = _window.  Both window and _window give me an undeclared identifier error.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something else wrong. I put the listener code into my -(void) playMovie method and I created a -(void) onPlayerWillExitFullScreen: (NSNotification *) aNotification method which is where I stop listening and put the above UIWindow code.

Comment: Try UIView *view = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.subviews lastObject];

Comment: Still get an error with reference to window in last line. '[window addSubview:view];'

Comment: Well yes, you'll need to change that reference too :)

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window addSubview:view]

Comment: Yeah there's a bug in iOS6 on iPhone that means that the MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification is not correctly raised :(

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void) moviePlayerWillExitFullScreen:(id)sender {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];

}
```

Guys try this... It works for me. I tried many other ways and only this one worked.